# How to add bunch of aspx files to a site definition sp2010 vs2010 project

Tags: sharepoint-2010, file, provisioning

I need to be able to deploy bunch of aspx files when a site (sub-site aka web) is provisioned. I added a feature but it seems whole feature thing has changed with vs 2010 or sp2010. I am totally lost. All I want to do is to deploy these pages when a web is provisioned. Is it possible?

Comment: I've only used 2007 myself... are you using VS2010?

Comment: I've tried to answer, but can you make your question a little more specific? Maybe explain the functionality you're trying to achieve and how far you're got with the Feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't drop aspx pages into SharePoint per say. If you want to add functionality, some of the options are:

1) Using Web Parts - probably the most popular method

2) User Controls

At the end of the day, you will create it as a Feature using VSeWSS 3.0 in VS and packaging/deploying it as a solution. Steer clear of trying to hack this up in SharePoint Designer - for one, you won't have source control like you have with a Feature.

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/UsingCodeBehindFilesInSharePointSites.aspx

http://www.codersbarn.com/?tag=/webpart